# Authentication with ICONIC 4, failure message won't display

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm trying to show the user a message that their login failed, but I can only act on a successful login.  The if statement below only runs if the login was successful.  How do I insert an else so I can set a flag to tell the user that the login failed.

** Edited code: Now works as it should.

```
//auth.service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  AUTH_SERVER_ADDRESS:  string  =  'http://localhost:3000';
  authSubject  =  new  BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private storage: Storage, public alertController: AlertController) { }

  login(user: User): Observable<AuthResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.AUTH_SERVER_ADDRESS}/login`, user).pipe(
      tap(async (res: AuthResponse) => {
        if (res.user) {
          await this.storage.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", res.user.access_token);
          await this.storage.set("EXPIRES_IN", res.user.expires_in);
          this.authSubject.next(true);
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

```
//login.page.ts
  showError: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;

  login(form){
    this.authService.login(form.value).subscribe(result => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl(`home`);
      },
      error => {    
        this.showError = true;
        //console.log(error.statusText);
        this.errorMessage = error.statusText;
      });
  }
```

And on my login page, I want to show the user an error on failed login:

```
//login.page.html
<div *ngIf="showError">Error: {{errorMessage}}! Please try again</div>
```

** Edited, login page will now display the error as I wanted.  I never could get the observable suggestion to work below.

Comment: Where can we find `this.authSubject`?

Comment: It's in auth.service.ts (added to code in question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let your login function in auth service return an observer when you find your data. If you don't find your data, the observer will return an error to the login function on your page. When you pass the data, you can close the Observable with `observer.complete()`

```js
//auth.service.ts
login(user: User): Observable<AuthResponse> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    this.httpClient.post(`${this.AUTH_SERVER_ADDRESS}/login`, user).pipe(
      tap(async (res: AuthResponse) => {
        if (res.user) {
          await this.storage.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", res.user.access_token);
          await this.storage.set("EXPIRES_IN", res.user.expires_in);
          observer.next(true); // send data to login page - subscribe
          observer.complete(); // close observable
        } else {
          observer.error();  // send error to login page - error
        }
      });
    });
  );
```

You can access the result here from `observer.next()` and the error from `observer.error()`

```js
login(form){
  this.authService.login(form.value).subscribe(
    result => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(`home`);
    },
    error => {    
      this.showError = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on observer.next(true);  Its saying that true is not assignable to AuthResponse.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I used the login(form) code in order to come up with the correct result.  I never got the observable code to work.